# Entity Framework keeps wanting to drop my database, why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I started my project with a code first database, but have now switched to a copy of the production database, and aim to let the test environment look more like the production environment. Hence, I don't want EF to create any tables (they're already there), and I sure as hell don't want it to drop any tables.

So, I have added this at the top of my Global.asax.cs Application_Start():

```
Database.SetInitializer<ProjectContext>(null);
```

But I still get an error message saying:

> "Cannot drop the database 'master' because it is a system database."

I thought it wasn't supposed to try and do drops after I initialize with null?

In my controller, I do the following:

```
 var userclientobjectvalues = context.UserClientObjectValues;
 var projects = context.Projects;
 var users = context.Users;
 var objectvalues = context.ObjectValues;
 var userProjects = userclientobjectvalues.Where(v => v.user_id == user);
```

The first four lines are just to make sure I am collecting the data correctly. And in debug mode, the results view expands just right, with all the data.

The aforementioned crash happens on the last line in the code block above.

From Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<ProjectContext>());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

Comment: Do you do anything else in `Application_Start()`? Anything that may somehow try to access a `ProjectContext`?

Comment: Do you get something meaningful from Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s); ?

Comment: An easy test: when you debug, if you set a breakpoint on the `Database.SetInitializer` line, does it hit it before you get the error?

Comment: @Jcl nothing that stands out to me. I'll update the OP with that entire method.

Comment: Oh and yes, it hits the SetInitializer line before I get the error.

Comment: Ok, then you should do a search for `Database.SetInitializer` in your whole project to see if you have somehow other conflicting line, and check `web.config` for `DatabaseInitializer` and see if there's something there... sounds like you are changing the initializer after that `Application_Start()`... it doesn't make sense otherwise

Comment: Adding isableDatabaseInitialization="true" to the context element in Web.Config solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: One thing that puzzles me is that it's trying to drop the `master` database, and you shouldn't be working on `master` with code first. Double check your connection strings aswell and make sure they have an `Initial Catalog` property setting the database name. I'll write an answer with all these findings

Answer (score 1):

After some back-and-forth fiddling in the comments, it seems the context was defined in `web.config` (instead of on code), so the initializer had to be set there aswell.

So set `disableDatabaseInitialization="true"` on the context line:

```xml
<context type="MyProject.MyContext, MyAssembly" disableDatabaseInitialization="true" />
```

Or if you want a different initializer, you can do:

```xml
<context type="MyProject.MyContext, MyAssembly">
  <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.MyDbInitializer, MyAssembly"> 
    <parameters> 
      <parameter value="MyConstructorParameters" /> 
    </parameters> 
  </databaseInitializer> 
</context>
```

Since the error was that it couldn't drop `master`, I'd also doublecheck the connection strings and make sure they have an `Initial Catalog` property: code-first contexts should not be working with the `master` database (at least for SQL Server).